# Containerized spring boot application with oracle database resetting connection

Tags: java, linux, spring, oracle, docker

I am having a problem with a containerized spring boot application using oracle database.
I successfully build my image but when I run it using docker the application gets stuck on getting a connection pool. The application runs with a connection reset exception and if I try to connect on it I get another connection reset exception, but if I refresh the page the application works normally until I try to use the application again later.

The Dockerfile is configured as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD *.jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

The application properties are pretty standard as well:

```
server.port = 8082
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:1521:<database>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

I'm building the image and running the docker container with the following commands:

```
docker build -t <image_name> .
docker run -p 8082:8082 -d <image_name>`
```

I have tried several things:

1. Googling the problem I found out that Oracle has entropy issues when running inside Linux so I added -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
2. That didn't work so I tried haveged tool for entropy. I didn't know exactly where to install it so I tried installing it in both places (inside the container using `RUN apk -U add haveged` and on the host machine (which is a ubuntu xenial 16.04.4))
3. That didnt work either so I tried to "hack it" by removing `/dev/random` from the container and replacing it with a symbolic link using  `ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random`, but even that didn't work so I tried changing the java.security property  `securerandom.source=file:/dev/random`

No options from above worked so I tried using HikariCP connection pooling but I had the same exception.

The stack trace for the exception :

```
    2017-10-24 09:00:01.133  WARN 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2017-10-24 09:00:01.133 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : IO Error: Connection reset
2017-10-24 09:00:01.142 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:153) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:185) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.findAllByOrderByIdAsc(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.generali.controller.MantisPowerController.getTbValues(MantisPowerController.java:89) ~[app.jar!/:0.1.4-RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, none of the things that I tried worked so I tried the following: I changed the Linux distribution from Ubuntu to CoreOS (which is made specifically for container use) and now it works great. The only problem is that CoreOS is a couple of versions behind with Docker, so I am limited in the things that I could use.

Answer (score 0):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    SLEEP=0

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8081
CMD echo "The application will start in ${SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${SLEEP} && \
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'
services:
    sample:
        image: image_name
        ports:
            - 8082:8082
```

BUILD IMAGE

> docker build -t image_name .

RUN

> docker-compose up -d

Comment: It did not work. Now I am getting a different exception and I can't connect to the database at all. Now the exception is:

`java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

Comment: Are you running your database as docker image?

Comment: No, I haven't found a docker image for an oracle 10g database so I was trying to connect to a database that is outside of the container